# Swift: Cannot invoke method with an argument list of type

Tags: swift, methods, signature

I have the Swift code below.

```
func beanManager(_ beanManager: PTDBeanManager!, didDiscover bean: PTDBean!, error: Error!) {
    if (bean.name == "SOME_NAME") {
        connectToBean(bean!)
        bean.delegate = self
        print("Connected to Bean")
    } else {
        print("Found a Bean not named SOME_NAME")
    }
}

func connectToBean(_ bean: PTDBean) {
    var error: NSError?
    deviceManager.connect(to: bean, error: &error)
    bean.delegate = self
}
```

Xcode is giving me an error

**Ambiguous use of 'connectToBean(_:error:)'**

Not sure what is causing this.

The method (SDK written in Obj-C) being called is:

```
-(void)connectToBean:(PTDBean*)bean error:(NSError**)error;
```

The method signature shown during auto-completion in Xcode is:

```
deviceManager?.connect(to: PTDBean!, error:NSErrorPointer)
```

Comment: There no need ! After bean cause bean is already unwrapped implicitly

Comment: Show the code for deviceManager connect method.

Answer (score 0):

There are no NSErrorPointer parameters any more. Use `try` instead:

```
do {
    try deviceManager?.connect(to: bean)
} catch {
    // whatever
}
```